# Conditional object creation within a stream in RxAndroid

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am still new to RxAndroid and I want to load a single object within a stream. This object can be loaded as an Observable from two different classes. In my szenario at first the object is loaded from `provider1`, if however `null` is provided, the object will be loaded from `provider2`.

My problem is that

- I have no idea how to elegantly check for `null`
- I have no idea how to deal with both, `Observable<MyObj>` and `MyObj` in the same method

At the moment my code looks like this

```
return provider1.getObject()
                .flatMap(o -> {
                    if(o == null) return provider2.getObject();
                    else return Observable.just(o);
                });
```

This doesn't really look nice, is there maybe an operator that I am missing? Or is there at least a method to flatten a single Observable so that I could do something like:

```
return provider1.getObject()
                .map(o -> {
                    if(o == null) return provider2.getObject().flatten();
                    else return o;
                });
```

Or am I just doing it totally the wrong way?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [switchIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchIfEmpty(rx.Observable)), such as

```
return provider1.getObject()
           .filter(o -> o != null)
           .switchIfEmpty(provider2.getObject());
```

BTW, `switchIfEmpty` is added since RxJava 1.0.5. You may need to specify the RxJava version in your build script.